# What are the requirements to convert a license from Iran to USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, cpl

What is required for someone who has CPL, IR and CFI licenses from Iran to fly in USA? What is the requirement to convert license?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot convert the CPL to FAA-CPL. What is possible is to obtain a FAA-PPL certificate by [verification](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/foreign_license_verification/) of the your current foreign license. This certificate will be valid as long as your foreign license is (plus medical conditions, and 24-months PPL flight review required for any PPL in the US).

With the PPL certificate, you will be able to obtain IR and CPL:

- Pass IR and CPL written tests.
- Attend training for IR and CPL practical checks.
- Accumulate at least 250 flight hours. Time in the foreign country with the foreign license will count as well, but at least 3 hours are required with the FAA instructor. The instructor will vouch for the candidate is ready for the check-ride.
- Pass CPL and IR practical checks.

A valid residence permit will be necessary to use the FAA-CPL.

The CFI roadmap is similar, written tests and checkrides are mandatory, there no minimum hours to be flown in the US. As a large part of the [knowledge required](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1185) is similar to many ICAO-member countries (teaching, meteorology, navigation, aerodynamics, etc) this shouldn't be a problem to be certified FAA CFI.

---

*Related:*

- [Do I need a PPL license for a CPL license?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8539/do-i-need-a-ppl-license-for-a-cpl-license)
- [I have a European EASA license - what do I need to do to be allowed to fly in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/183/i-have-a-european-easa-license-what-do-i-need-to-do-to-be-allowed-to-fly-in-th?rq=1)
- [Can a pilot with an ICAO Multi-Crew Pilot License fly an airliner into the U.S.?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/can-a-pilot-with-an-icao-multi-crew-pilot-license-fly-an-airliner-into-the-u-s?lq=1)

---

*References:*

- Required knowledge [FAR 61.123](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#sp14.2.61.f) et seqq.
- Required flight experience [FAR 61.129](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1129).
- [Pilot certification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_certification_in_the_United_States) in the US on Wikipedia.
- Process for foreign CPL to FAA-PPL conversion ([FAR 61.75](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_175)).
- Flight Instructors [FAR 62.181](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#sp14.2.61.h)

Comment: Could you clarify your remark that "A valid residence permit will be necessary to use the FAA-CPL"?  Where is this requirement, and what if the aircraft was being flown outside the US?

Comment: I'm not a US citizen. I refer to the section *Non-Resident Workers* in [Can foreign pilots get an FAA ATPL and work for a US-based commercial airline?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13579/can-foreign-pilots-get-an-faa-atpl-and-work-for-a-us-based-commercial-airline) for the case of a pilot without a Green Card. My understanding is that you cannot be employed by an airline. Am I wrong here? For what it is worth, this discussion on [PPRuNe](http://www.pprune.org/north-america/305828-expat-pilots-job-usa.html), very confused.