# What is the procedure to obtain an FAA ATP while in the United States for a holder of a CPL from Pakistan?

Tags: faa-regulations

I hold a CPL from Pakistan and currently fly an A320. I have accumulated over 4000 flight hours. If I visit the United States, what is the procedure to obtain a FAA ATP certificate?

Comment: Your question is more or less answered [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13579/62). You need to be in the US legally (visa, green card), get TSA approval (if necessary) and be able to pay for your training.

Comment: @Pondlife I think that he wants to **convert** his foreign license to a US license.

Comment: While [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/69) covers converting an EASA license, the process is the same.

Comment: @Lnafziger Good point, that could be it. But I don't think the question you linked to applies either: you can only get a private certificate under 61.75, not an ATP. For an ATP he still has to do the tests, at least according to 61.153.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that need to be accomplished.

1. Get a [letter of authenticity](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/foreign_license_verification/) from the FAA validating your license is valid and from an ICAO contracting country.
2. Study and pass the ATP multi-engine written test.  You may have to get a graduation certificate from a school offering the CTP course.
3. Apply for and receive TSA clearance.
   https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/?acct_type=c&section=WN
4. Take the FAA ATP practical test in an A320 airplane or FFS simulator.  It is best to contact a training center on what is required.